# why do i need to overide the prototype.constructor value?

Tags: javascript

I was reading about prototyping in javascript, and if I need to inherit from another object.

I do the following :

```
function Employee() {
    this.name = '';
    this.dept = 'general';
}

function Manager() {
    Employee.call(this); 
    this.reports = [];
}
```

The line `Employee.call(this);` works, but in the documentation, it's mentioned that I also need to do the following:

> Add a prototypical instance as the value of the `prototype` property of the constructor function, then override the `prototype.constructor` to the constructor function:
>
> ```
> Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
> Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
> ```

I've commented out those 2 lines, and still be able to get the dept value of the Manager object.

```
//Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
//Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
var jim = new Employee;
console.log(jim.dept);  // print general 
var sally = new Manager;
console.log(sally.dept); // still printing general
```

So what is the importance of those 2 lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

What those two lines provide is the ability to look up for methods in `Employee.prototype` in case the lookup in `Manager.prototype` doesn't find anything.

Accessing a data member works because you called `Employee` explicitly (so the per-instance data was properly set up), but wouldn't work when looking for `Employee` methods or other per-class data.

In my opinion it's much easier to understand if you think to what really happens at low level when Javascript engine resolves

```
x.y
```

1. the object `x` is checked for an `y` member, if it's found that's the value used.
2. if it's not found instead of immediately return `undefined` the object prototype is checked for the member.

Note that the search performed in 2 ma trigger another search on the prototype of the prototype and so on.

The object prototype is set when you do `x = new X` and the value used is `X.prototype`, whatever it is at that time.
In other words

```
let x = new X;
```

is more or less the same as

```
let x = Object.create(X.prototype);
X.call(x);
```

As a somewhat convoluted example consider:

```
function X(n) { this.n = n;}
X.prototype.show = function() { console.log(this.n); };

x = new X(42);
x.show(); /// --> 42

X.prototype.show = function() { console.log("Hey..."); };
y = new X(99);

y.show(); /// --> Hey
x.show(); /// --> Hey (we replaced a member in same X.prototype object)

// Now I am instead replacing the object that will be used as prototype
X.prototype = {show: function(){ console.log("Back", this.n); }};

z = new X(21);
x.show(); /// --> Hey... (x instance was constructed before the change)
z.show(); /// --> Back 21  (updated prototype in action)
```

Comment: but i've added a method called printName in employee 
and called it in a manager object and it's worked fine without using those 2 lines